# Mac browser messing up page

Tags: wordpress, macos

I have a webpage that is running in wordpress using thesis.  The page shows up fine on a PC but the sidebar is being kicked down on any mac web browser.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I've checked the content, sidebar, padding, margins, etc to make sure they aren't too wide to fit in the wrapper, but I don't see the problem.  I need a fresh pair of eyes. 
Can anyone help?
http://www.thesurgicalsolution.com/

Comment: "Any Mac web browser" - which versions of which browsers? FF3? FF4? Safari (which version[s])? Chrome (which version[s])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be resolved, for Safari 5.0.5 at least, with a `clear:both` added to `div#content`; but I'm not entirely sure why. Some of the body text is still spilling out to the right, behind the sidebars, so there may be a width/padding/margin problem there as well.

Comment: You should still fix the validation errors @songdogtech pointed out though *8-) With the final `</div>` you might find that `clear` isn't necessary after all.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an ending `</div>` tag, which will affect the sidebar placement, among other code errors. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of thesurgicalsolution.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.thesurgicalsolution.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.